# How to convert NSString to C string?

Tags: objective-c

I know that this question is a possible duplicate, but even after looking at some Google tutorials and questions even on this forum none of them gives me a decent answer about this subject.

I have:

```
NSString *str = @"text";
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
char cstring [512] = str;
```

(this only shows what I want to do, after looking at Apple's NSString Class Ref I didn't even think about using it).

Up to now I have:

```
char command [512] = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Still, with that I get errors.

Any solution?

Answer (score 141):

try `const char *command = [str UTF8String];`

Answer (score 37):

A c string is returned as a pointer, not as an array of characters. To use it, you can change your variable to a pointer.

```
const char *command = [theString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Since you want the UTF8 encoding, you can use the `UTF8String` convenience method.

```
const char *command = [theString UTF8String];
```

If you need the data to be stored in a character array, you can use the `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` method, passing the array as the buffer. This will allow you to store the string directly to the buffer, and will tell you if the buffer is too small.

```
char command[512];
if(![theString getCString:command maxLength:sizeof(command)/sizeof(*command) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) {
    NSLog(@"Command buffer too small");
}
```

Comment: sizeof(command)/sizeof(*command) + 1 to account for the null terminator